# How to solve error that is shown after adding you tube link to iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have set the youtube link in the iframe in my website. But there is a error shows in the inspect element. So, I want to know, the reason for that error and how I solve that error.

> chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>   chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>   globalf39e.js:1522 otherbrowser
>   chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Thankz

Answer (score 2):

That Error is from the Google Chromecast Plugin. I do not think it has anything to do with your site.

**dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast-beta/dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm?hl=en

Comment: Is there any soloution to remove that warnings ?

Comment: Just so we're, you have no control over the error message. The Developer of the plugin would have to fix it as it is their code causing the issue. If you want to test your site, and see the debug error. You would need to remove the plugin and re-install when done. Please mark as answer if this did in deed answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

In the youtube iframe link you can replace the `youtube.com/embed/*...` with   `youtube.com/v/*...`